# How to mark all the text between " and " in office word, for replacing e.g. colour?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have been writing on a novel for a while and had the idea that I wanted all my dialog "bla. bla. bla." in a different colour, to make it easier to read.
Since it is getting quite long, I wondered if it was possible to use the replacement system to search for all the dialog boxes and colouring it in one easy sweep?

I know how to colour replaced text, I just don't know how what to write in the [Find it] box for it to recognize: "bla. bla. bla."

Comment: If you are going to distribute this yourself in electronic form, such coloring could be preserved if it is supported by the output format and the software that translates it to that format.  But if you plan to have it published in printed hard copy, you would need to do it another way, if the publisher is set up to handle it at all.  You would typically need to include some form of searchable codes for starting and ending the color, and you would want to coordinate how to do it with the publisher.  (cont'd)

Comment: Just asking them to search for matching pairs of quotes wouldn't likely be adequate, and wouldn't be reliable since quotes could be used for things other than dialog.  And if you have a typo, like a missing a quote or a doubled quote, the result would be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a wildcard search and replace. Here is a article on this: [How to replace text in quotation marks with italic or highlighted text minus the quotes](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ReplaceQuotes.htm)

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Even while links still work, the content can't be indexed to help people find the solution.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Find and Replace** dialog ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> )
2. Expand it: **More >>>**
3. Check **Use wildcards**
4. In the **Find what** enter: `“(*)”`
5. In the **Replace With** enter: `“\1”` (the `\1` stands for the 1st matching group `()`).
6. Define new color via **Format** button at the bottom.